# Como usar sessão para autenticacao em MVC 4 com C#?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, autenticação, session

O meu cenário é o seguinte. Tenho uma aplicação MVC 4. No meu controller faço a verificação do usuario logado e senha. (Acho que) Coloquei os dados do usuário numa sessão após os dados estarem verificados e corretos.

Minhas páginas são cshtml (Razor). E possuo uma master page que utilizarei os dados da Session para mostrar o usuário logado por exemplo.

Caso os dados do login não estejam corretos a sessão ficará vazia e eu redirecionarei para a página de login.

**Dúvidas:**

- Como fazer a abertura da sessão e o fechamento da mesma?
- Como definir o tempo de inatividade para encerrá-la?
- O que é preciso para que o sistema só permita acesso direto pelas URLs após o login e session ativa.

**Minha Action da Tela de Login após o envio dos dados:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UsuarioDTO dto)
    {
        UsuarioDTO ValidarLogin = null;

        UsuarioDTO usuario = new UsuarioDTO();
        usuario.Login = dto.Login;
        usuario.Senha = dto.Senha;

        negocio = new AeroJetNEGOCIO();

        try
        {
            ValidarLogin = negocio.Login.LogarUsuario(usuario);

            usuario = ValidarLogin;

            Session["usuarioLogado"] = usuario;                   

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "CadastroCliente");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.classe = "alert";
            ViewBag.msg = e.Message;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

*OBS: Essa session ai que eu inclui não sei nem como ela se comporta. Foi apenas uma tentativa.*

**Essa tela redireciona para outra Action de outro Controller que é uma tela para um usuário já logado.**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
         return View();
    }
```

*OBS: Não sei se devo colocar algum código para validar a Session ai. Preciso de ajuda nessa parte.*

Se precisarem do cshtml da master page ou da página que entra depois do login eu posto.

Comment: Creio que [esta pergunta que respondi](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21608/pagina-de-login-e-senha/21609#21609) resolva bem o seu problema.

Comment: Vou dar uma estudada na sua solução para tentar implementar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Crie uma **SessionManager**

```
public static class SessionManager
{
    public static void RegisterSession(string key, object obj)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = obj;
    }

    public static void FreeSession(string key)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = null;
    }


    public static bool CheckSession(string key)
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[key] != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static bool CheckSession(string key, System.Web.HttpContextBase contexto)
    {
        if (contexto.Session[key] != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static object ReturnSessionObject(string key)
    {
        if (CheckSession(key))
            return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
        else
            return null;
    }

    public static object ReturnSessionObject(string key, System.Web.HttpContextBase contexto)
    {
        if (CheckSession(key, contexto))
            return contexto.Session[key];
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Crie uma **CustomAuthorizeAttribute**

```
public struct SessionKeys
{
    public const string Usuario = "Usuario";
}

public class ResearchAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (SessionManager.CheckSession(SessionKeys.Usuario) == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (SessionManager.CheckSession(SessionKeys.Usuario) == false)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                            new RouteValueDictionary 
                    {
                        { "action", "Login" },
                        { "controller", "Research" }
                    });
        }
        else
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Crie uma **CustomAutenticadoModelBinder**

```
class ResearchAutenticadoModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object GetValue(ControllerContext controllerContext)//, string modelName, Type modelType, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        var modelo = new ResearchAutenticadoBindModel();
        modelo.Usuario = SessionManager.ReturnSessionObject(SessionKeys.Usuario, controllerContext.HttpContext).ToString();
        return modelo;
    }

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext", "controllerContext is null.");
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext", "bindingContext is null.");

        return GetValue(controllerContext);
    }
}
```

Adicione seu CustomModelBinder no **Application_Start**

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(ResearchAutenticadoBindModel), new ResearchAutenticadoModelBinder());
```

Agora voce poderá registrar o login nos **Controllers**:

```
SessionManager.RegisterSession(SessionKeys.Usuario, "Usuario XYZ");
```

E pode utilizar seu Autorize nas *Actions* restritas:

```
    [ResearchAuthorize]
    public ActionResult New(ResearchAutenticadoBindModel login)
    {
        return Edit(login, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, amanha testarei sua solução.

Comment: SessionManager, CustomAuthorizeAttribute e CustomAutenticadoModelBinder são arquivos de classe separados? Que nome devo colocar neles?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo, isso mesmo joao, voce pode dar o nome que quiser para essas classes. Eu utilizei basicamente essas três seguidas de um sufixo auto-explicativo.