# Criar Roles para Ocultar/Mostrar Menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo minha primeira aplicação em ***Asp.NET MVC*** e criando agora a parte de restrição e autorização dos usuários. Gostaria de fazer isso de forma que os menus da minha aplicação só ficassem acessíveis a determinados usuários.

*Por exemplo:*

```
@if ("administrador")
{
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Agenda", "Index", "Agenda")</li>
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Criar", "Create", "Agenda")</li>
}
```

Ou seja, no meu layout identificar qual tipo de usuário pode ver aquele menu. Então minhas dúvidas são:

1. Como por exemplo atribuir quais usuários são administradores?
2. Como criar um controller identificando qual usuário está logado ( eu uso windows authentication )
3. Verificar qual grupo ele faz parte? Eu não uso nem `Cookie`, nem `Session` na minha aplicação, é tudo via Autenticação do Windows?

Eu obtenho a autenticação do usuário através de uma classe

```
public static class UserDetails
{
    public static string GetMatricula(string userName)
    {
        string matricula = userName.Substring(userName.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);
        return matricula;
    }
}
```

E no controller tenho

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var matricula = UserDetails.GetMatricula(User.Identity.Name);
    var usuario = db.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Matricula == matricula);
}
```

O campo matrícula é o mesmo que o usuário loga no *Windows*. Dessa forma assim que o usuário entra na aplicação, automaticamente já abre com as informações dele de **nome** e **matrícula**.

Answer (score 2):

## Como por exemplo atribuir quais usuários são administradores?

Usando *Roles*. Por exemplo:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrador")) { ... }
```

## Como criar um controller identificando qual usuário está logado (eu uso windows authentication) e verificar qual grupo ele faz parte?

Na verdade você não necessariamente precisa usar um *Controller*. O melhor é utilizar algum provedor de gerenciamento de usuários e perfis como o `ASP.NET Membership` e o `ASP.NET Identity`.

No seu caso, eu criaria um *Model* novo chamado **Perfil**:

```
public class Perfil 
{
    [Key]
    public int PerfilId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioEmPerfil> UsuariosEmPerfis { get; set; }
}
```

E mais uma tabela associativa, por exemplo:

```
public class UsuarioEmPerfil 
{
    [Key]
    public int UsuarioEmPerfilId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_UsuarioEmPerfil_UsuarioId_PerfilId", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_UsuarioEmPerfil_UsuarioId_PerfilId", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public int PerfilId { get; set; }        

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
    public virtual Perfil Perfil { get; set; }
}
```

[`[Index]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute(v=vs.113).aspx), introduzido nesta forma a partir do Entity Framework 6.1.0, garante a unicidade do registro associativo. Validações adicionais podem ser necessárias na aplicação para evitar erros estranhos de duplicidade de chave para o usuário.

`Usuario` receberia a associação de Usuários com Perfis:

```
public class Usuario
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioEmPerfil> UsuariosEmPerfis { get; set; }
}
```

Reimplementaria o `RoleProvider` seguindo o esboço [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21609/2999) (apenas repare que eu uso o nome `Role` ao invés do nome `Perfil`).

Por fim, usaria o seguinte comando na View:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrador")) { ... }
```

Este comando usa o método `IsUserInRole` do seu `RoleProvider`.

Comment: Editei a pergunta @Cigano Morrison Mendez. Então, nesse "Administrador" como eu informo quais são os administradores? Pra fazer via controller como seria? Preciso dizer que tais matrículas são administradores, tais são usuários comuns, e outras usuários avançados, de modo que quando entrar na aplicação só esteja visível o menu correspondente pra cada

Comment: @kLucas Editei a resposta.

Comment: ainda preciso de ajuda. Tentei com o ASP.NET membership mas não tive muito sucesso juntamente com o meu modo de autenticação do usuário. O model e a view que vc passou nessa resposta estão claros pra mim, mas o IsInRole e o RoleProvider do link que passou da outra resposta não. Lá está considerando login e senha. Eu não tenho isso. Como seria usando windows authentication? Ainda não ficou claro pra mim, desculpe

Comment: O que mais importa pra mim é ocultar o menu de alguns usuários

Comment: @kLucas Implemente apenas o `CustomRoleProvider`. Não precisa implementar o `CustomMembershipProvider` (que é o que tem senha).