# Segurança e autorização usando Roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Estou terminando minha aplicação configurando a autorização e permissão dos usuários a aplicação. Minha ideia é mexer no layout de modo que os menus e submenus só estejam visíveis para quem tem autorização para a mesma. De acordo com o que pesquisei preciso criar Roles para  atribuir no meu layout

```
 @if (User.IsInRole("Usuário")
```

Pois bem. Tenho 3 tabelas no meu banco preparadas para fazer esse controle. Seguem meus models.

```
    public class Perfil
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Matricula { get; set; } // Esse campo é o mesmo de login do usuário no sistema

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PerfiRole> PerfilRoles { get; set; }
}


    public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; } // Administrador, Gerente, Usuário

    public virtual ICollection<PerfiRole> PerfilRoles { get; set; }
}


    public class PerfiRole
{
    [Key]
    public int PerfilRoleId { get; set; }

    public int Roleid { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

    public int Perfilid { get; set; }
    public virtual Perfil Perfil { get; set; }

    public int Matricula { get; set; }



}
```

Todas as tabelas já estão carregadas com seus devidos perfis e atribuições de Administrador, Usuário e Gerente. 
Estou usando windows authentication onde o campo Matricula da tabela Perfil é o mesmo de entrada do usuário no windows, e quando este acessa a aplicação, ela já abre com seus dados de Perfil puxada do login sem necessidade de 'usuário e senha' para entrar na aplicação. 
Enfim, a partir disso queria fechar o mecanismo para quando o usuário entrar na aplicação, carregue seus dados automaticamente como já é feito e aparecessem apenas os menus correspondentes a seu perfil como já definido no banco de dados. Gostaria de saber como fica o controller para que eu consiga realizar isso. Tentei alguns métodos e vi alguns exemplos mas nenhum parecido com o que eu preciso. Também preciso saber o que mudar no webconfig. Toda ajuda e sugestão é bem vinda

**EDIT**

```
    public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{

    public override string ApplicationName
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
    {
        using (var db = new DataContext())
        {
            // check if role exits
            return db.Roles.Any(r => r.Nome == roleName);
        }
    }

    public override string[] GetAllRoles()
    {
        List<string> roles = new List<string>();

        using (var db = new DataContext())
        {
            try
            {
                var dbRoles = db.Roles.ToList();

                foreach (var role in dbRoles)
                {
                    roles.Add(role.Nome);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { throw e; }
        }

        return roles.ToArray();
    }

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        List<string> roles = new List<string>();

        using (var db = new DataContext())
        {
            try
            {
                var dbRoles = db.Perfis.Where(p => p.Matricula == username).ToList();

                foreach (var role in dbRoles)
                {
                    roles.Add(role.Nome);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { throw e; }
        }

        return roles.ToArray();
    }

}
```

Comment: Você implementou um `RoleProvider` para que o comando `User.IsInRole()` funcione corretamente?

Comment: Não, é isso que eu preciso saber como implementar.

Comment: Ou @CiganoMorrisonMendez caso tenha uma outra maneira que eu consiga fazer o mesmo sem a necessidade de [RoleProvider]

Comment: A melhor maneira é usando o `RoleProvider`. Veja a resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Parte da resposta que eu vou descrever aqui começa [nesta outra resposta que fiz, explicando o esquema inteiro da topologia do Membership](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21608/pagina-de-login-e-senha/21609#21609). Pulando para a parte que interessa, implemente o seguinte:

## 1. CustomRoleProvider

Não precisa ser este nome. Pode ser qualquer outro. Não esquema de atualizar seu `Web.config`, mas a ideia geral é que esta classe derivada tenha o seguinte:

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    // A interface pede a declaração explícita de ApplicationName, mas a 
    // implementação é opcional. Apenas declare para evitar erros.
    public override string ApplicationName
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    // Este método adicionará vários usuários a várias roles.
    public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
    { ... }

    // Este método cria uma Role
    public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
    { ... }

    // Este método exclui uma Role
    public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
    { ... }

    // Este método encontrará usuários que batam com uma determinada expressão
    // passada por parâmetro
    public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
    { ... }

    // Este método devolverá todas as Roles
    public override string[] GetAllRoles()
    { ... }

    // Este método devolverá todas as Roles de um usuário
    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    { ... }

    // Este método devolverá todos os usuários de uma Role
    public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
    { ... }

    // Este método verifica se um usuário pertence a uma Role
    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    { ... }

    // Este método remove os usuários das Roles passadas como parâmetro
    public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
    { ... }

    // Este método verifica se uma Role existe.
    public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
    { ... }
}
```

## 2. Web.config

Adicione o seguinte ao seu `Web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="MeuProjeto.Site.Infrastructure.CustomRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
<configuration>
```

## 3. Implementar os métodos de acordo com a sua topologia

Agora é só implementar. Vou dar alguns exemplos dentro da sua topologia:

```
    public override string[] GetAllRoles()
    {
        List<string> roles = new List<string>();

        using (var context = new MeuProjetoContext())
        {
            try
            {
                var dbRoles = context.Roles.ToList();

                foreach (var role in dbRoles)
                {
                    roles.Add(role.Nome);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { throw e; }
        }

        return roles.ToArray();
    }

    // Estou supondo aqui que "User", no seu caso, é "Perfil"
    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        List<string> roles = new List<string>();

        using (var context = new MeuProjetoContext())
        {
            try
            {
                var dbRoles = context.Perfis.Where(p => p.Nome == username).ToList();

                foreach (var perfilRole in dbRoles.Select(r => r.PerfilRole))
                {
                    roles.Add(perfilRole.Role.Nome);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { throw e; }
        }

        return roles.ToArray();
    }
```

Se precisar de mais exemplos, vou melhorando a resposta.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54214/discussion-on-answer-by-cigano-morrison-mendez-seguranca-e-autorizacao-usando-ro)