# Como colocar login em projeto WEB asp.Net MVC No Authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autenticação, asp.net-identity

Bem, criei um projeto WEB e de início imaginei que não iria ser necessário acrescentar o sistema de login, então usei o template `No Authentication` (até aí tudo bem...). O problema é que agora eu gostaria de acrescentar o login sem ter que migrar meu projeto para um novo. Não sei se fazendo manualmente o módulo de login ele ficaria realmente seguro. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Ficar fica, mas antes preciso saber se você gostaria de usar um *template* comum de projeto ASP.NET MVC ou faz questão de escrever manualmente o seu mecanismo.

Comment: Prefiro usar o _template_ mesmo.

Comment: Posso escrever uma resposta mais dentro do seu problema ou algo mais didático. O que prefere?

Comment: Obrigado desde já meu amigo. Bem, eu gostaria de resolver meu problema, mas também gostaria de aprender um pouco mais. Você teria tempo e disponibilidade para fazer algo bem didático? (Obs: Sou iniciante)

Comment: Parece que o @CiganoMorrisonMendez vai fazer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como resposta mais simples e que dá menos trabalho, o melhor seria gerar uma outra solução com *Individual User Accounts* e transferir os fontes da solução antiga para a solução nova, mas vale a pena adensar a explicação para o caso de uma solução totalmente customizada de autenticação.

A segurança é um aspecto que pode sim ser obtido através da implementação manual do seu próprio esquema de autenticação. Como o ASP.NET Identity é extensível, a alfaiataria se torna muito simples, embora o conjunto de elementos não seja). Apesar de bem trabalhosa, a reimplementação das classes pode ser muito vantajosa para quem quiser ter total controle sobre cada aspecto que envolve autenticação e informações relativas a ela. Apenas atente para o objetivo de cada componente, o que vou explicar abaixo.

## Classe `SignInManager`

Esta é a classe que realiza a autenticação de fato. Ao gerar um projeto com *Individual User Accounts*, por exemplo, é gerado um *Controller* (`AccountsController.cs`) que faz uso de `SignInManager`. Até a data desta resposta, `SignInManager` não é documentada na MSDN. O que existe [são exemplos](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/wiki/Using-Identity-in-ASP.NET-applications) e [o código fonte](http://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/2.2.0-alpha1-140723/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/SignInManager.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin). Mesmo os exemplos não são específicos para uma alfaiataria adequada.

No mesmo projeto gerado, temos ainda a seguinte classe que deriva de `SignInManager`:

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

Aqui:

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
```

Especifico claramente que `SignInManager` irá usar como classe de usuários `ApplicationUser`, e o `Id` (identificador) de um usuário será `string`. Você poderia muito bem indexar usuário usando números inteiros, por exemplo. Basta mudar o tipo passado de `string` para `int`.

Já `ApplicationUser` é derivada de `IdentityUser`. Para o caso do *Individual User Accounts*, que é um projeto que usa *Entity Framework*, usar `IdentityUser` está ok. Caso seu projeto use outra tecnologia para abstração do banco de dados, `ApplicationUser` não poderia derivar `IdentityUser`.

## Classe [`IdentityUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identityuser%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

`IdentityUser` implementa vários conceitos que podem deixar sua autenticação bem abrangente. O protótipo padrão da classe sem especificação das classes genéricas é:

```
public class IdentityUser : IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>, IUser, IUser<string>
```

- `string` é a representação da chave do usuário. Assim como em `ApplicationSignInManager`, estamos considerando que o identificador de um usuário é uma `string`;
- `IdentityUserLogin` possui os dados de login e os dados de um provedor de login. Suponha que sua aplicação irá autenticar usando um login do Google. Esta classe permite que isto seja feito;
- `IdentityUserRole` é uma classe que pode associar um usuário a uma *Role* (a melhor tradução para *role* é "perfil"). Isto existe para preservar o antigo esquema de permissionamento por perfil que existia na arquitetura anterior, conhecida como ASP.NET Membership;
- `IdentityUserClaim` associa um usuário a uma *claim*. Em língua portuguesa, *claim* seria algo como uma "credencial", mas é mais granular que isso. Uma *claim* é qualquer informação que faz parte da identificação de um usuário na aplicação. Por exemplo, seu CPF pode ser uma *claim*. Seu RG também.

E como um usuário é criado? A resposta esta na próxima classe.

## Classe [`UserManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613290%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

`UserManager` é uma (enorme) classe cujos métodos criam, alteram ou excluem qualquer usuário ou informações relativas a ele, como *roles* e *claims*. Para um verdadeiro esquema customizado dentro do ASP.NET Identity, é preciso reimplementar esta classe. A título de curiosidade, [o fonte dela está aqui](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.0.0-rtm-140226/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core).

## Outros Esquemas de Autenticação

O ASP.NET Identity pode ser tremendamente complexo para quem está começando a escrever sua própria camada de autenticação. Neste âmbito, vale a pena voltar um pouco atrás e dominar o [ASP.NET Membership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx), mais limitado, porém mais simples. Aqui no site já dei várias respostas sobre ele que podem ser úteis:

- [Tela de login com membership e mvc5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27738/tela-de-login-com-membership-e-mvc5/28387?s=1|2.8649#28387)
- [Segurança e autorização usando Roles](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25567/seguran%C3%A7a-e-autoriza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-usando-roles/25586#25586)
- [Como criar uma página de login e senha no ASP.NET?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21608/pagina-de-login-e-senha/21609#21609)

Comment: você é fera cara! Muito obrigado mesmo por toda essa explicação. Fiz tudo como o indicado, tive alguns problemas, mas consegui resolver lendo outras ajudas.

Answer (score 2):

Se for usar o ASP.NET Identity, que é ótimo, veja esse post em que o usuário que recebeu a recompensa mostra como incluir o ASP.NET Identity de um template **SEM** o ASP.NET Identity - Sem autentição incluída - **opção de template marcado com o `No Authentication`**: **[Exemplo do ASP.NET Identity usando o SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16190/25712)**

Todavia, seria talvez interessante você criar um outro projeto do ASP.NET MVC com o ASP.NET Identity e copiar as classes e configurações. Por conta das mudanças que já teve.

Comment: Uma curiosidade sobre essa resposta que você mencionou. A pessoa na época não terminou a resposta e usou outro usuário dela mesma pra atribuir a recompensa. Vou escrever outra resposta mais completa.

Comment: @Cigano, interessante.

Comment: Ficarei muito grato!

Comment: Só não entendi o que tem haver.. rs

Comment: Na verdade preciso contar uma historinha aqui. O autor da pergunta na época pediu pra que a resposta ensinasse como fazer especificamente usando *No Authentication* mas sem entender o *Individual User Accounts*, então escrevi uma resposta explicando o *Individual User Accounts*. Embora seja a resposta aceita, o autor da pergunta tinha 2 usuários: um ele usava pra responder, e o outro pra votar a favor do primeiro e transferir reputação. Reparem que a resposta ficou pela metade. Ele nem fala de `SignInManager`, que é a parte mais importante da autenticação. Vou responder para ficar mais claro.

Comment: @Cigano, reclamação computada.

Comment: @Jedaias, siga ele que te ajudará

Comment: Ficarei na expectativa, mas desde já agradeço.