# Personalizar Individual User Accounts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Bem, tenho um projeto Web Asp.Net MVC que usa **Individual User Accounts** e eu gostaria de usar uma tabela específica em meu banco de dados e uma classe diferente para gerenciar o login de usuários. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: possível duplicata de [Exemplo do ASP.NET Identity usando o SQL Server](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15485/exemplo-do-asp-net-identity-usando-o-sql-server)

Comment: Não é duplicata. Aguarde que estou escrevendo uma resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Antes de mais nada, é importante ler esta resposta para termos um ponto de partida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67140/2999).

Para fins desta resposta, gerei um novo projeto com *Individual User Accounts*. É um bom ponto de partida para a alfaiataria que faremos.

Como um "passo zero", sugiro a criação da seguinte estrutura de diretórios no seu projeto:

[image: Infrastructure]

## Passo 1: Criando seus *Models*

O projeto já vem configurado com um contexto já pronto para o Entity Framework e alguns *Models*, bem como uma conexão para uma base [LocalDb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh510202.aspx). Você pode inserir seus novos *Models* no contexto existente ou criar outro.

Para fins de exemplo, farei tudo em um contexto em separado, justamente para atingir o objetivo didático da resposta.

Criei um contexto em separado, em `Models:`

```
namespace CustomIndividualUserAccounts.Models
{
    public class CustomContext : DbContext
    {
        public CustomContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection") { }
    }
}
```

Habilito uma configuração de *Migrations* para este contexto novo. Abro o Package Manager Console (<kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Other Windows</kbd> > <kbd>Package Manager Console</kbd>) e digito:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName CustomIndividualUserAccounts.Models.CustomContext
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
Code First Migrations enabled for project CustomIndividualUserAccounts.
```

Se você não conhece *Migrations*, [veja este link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj591330.aspx).

Crio uma classe `Usuario`:

```
namespace CustomIndividualUserAccounts.Models
{
    [DisplayColumn("Nome")]
    public class Usuario
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid UsuarioId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String Nome { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public String Senha { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Uma classe `Perfil`:

```
namespace CustomIndividualUserAccounts.Models
{
    [DisplayColumn("Nome")]
    public class Perfil
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid PerfilId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String Nome { get; set; }
    }
}
```

E uma classe `UsuarioPerfil`:

```
namespace CustomIndividualUserAccounts.Models
{
    public class UsuarioPerfil
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid UsuarioPerfilId { get; set; }
        public Guid UsuarioId { get; set; }
        public Guid PerfilId { get; set; }

        public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
        public virtual Perfil Perfil { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Opcionalmente, você pode colocar as propriedades de navegação da tabela `UsuarioPerfil` em `Usuario` e em `Perfil`:

```
[DisplayColumn("Nome")]
public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UsuarioId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public String Senha { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioPerfil> UsuarioPerfis { get; set; }
}

[DisplayColumn("Nome")]
public class Perfil
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PerfilId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioPerfil> UsuarioPerfis { get; set; }
}
```

Adicione 3 `DbSet<>` no contexto:

```
namespace CustomIndividualUserAccounts.Models
{
    public class CustomContext : DbContext
    {
        public CustomContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection") { }

        public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Perfil> Perfis { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UsuarioPerfil> UsuariosPerfis { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Crie uma *Migration* para eles e atualize o banco de dados pelo Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Add-Migration Inicial
Scaffolding migration 'Inicial'.
The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration Inicial' again.
PM> Update-Database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [201506031521384_Inicial].
Applying explicit migration: 201506031521384_Inicial.
Running Seed method.
```

## Passo 2: Trocando `UserManager`

Em `Infrastructure\Authentication`, crio uma classe chamada `CustomUserManager` e faço ela derivar de `UserManager`, passando meu usuário como tipo genérico exigido:

```
namespace CustomIndividualUserAccounts.Infrastructure.Authentication
{
    public class CustomUserManager : UserManager<Usuario>
    {
    }
}
```

Aqui possivelmente o Visual Studio irá reclamar que `Usuario` não implementa `IUser<>`. Podemos ajustar a classe `Usuario` sem necessidade de gerar *Migrations* adicionais. A minha ficou assim:

```
namespace CustomIndividualUserAccounts.Models
{
    [DisplayColumn("Nome")]
    public class Usuario : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<String>
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid UsuarioId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String Nome { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public String Senha { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<UsuarioPerfil> UsuarioPerfis { get; set; }

        public string Id
        {
            get { return UsuarioId.ToString(); }
        }

        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return Nome;
            }
            set
            {
                Nome = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Há várias coisas que podem ser ajustadas aqui. Veja a implementação de `ApplicationUserManager` em `App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs` para exemplos do que pode ser configurado.

## Passo 3: Trocando `SignInManager`

`SignInManager` é a classe responsável pela autenticação. Está referenciada em `Controllers\AccountController.cs` e sua implementação derivada está em `App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs` (classe `ApplicationSignInManager`).

Aqui vou criar minha implementação de `SignInManager`.

```
namespace CustomIndividualUserAccounts.Infrastructure.Authentication
{
    public class CustomSignInManager : SignInManager<Usuario, string>
    {
    }
}
```

## Passo 4: Reimplementando métodos

Aqui é um passo particular. Cada implementação tem seu conjunto de diferenças em relação ao ASP.NET Identity nativo. O que posso fornecer são exemplos do que pode ser reimplementado, para que esta resposta não fique extensa demais.

O exemplo abaixo eu reimplemento a autenticação propriamente dita:

```
using CustomIndividualUserAccounts.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CustomIndividualUserAccounts.Infrastructure.Authentication
{
    public class CustomSignInManager : SignInManager<Usuario, string>
    {
        public CustomContext contexto = new CustomContext();

        public override async Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
        {
            var usuario = await contexto.Usuarios.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Nome == userName);
            if (usuario == null) return SignInStatus.Failure;

            if (usuario.Senha != password) return SignInStatus.Failure;

            return SignInStatus.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Repare que tomei uma série de liberdades didáticas. Nem de longe este procedimento é seguro, a senha não está criptografada, etc, etc, etc. O objetivo é apenas demonstrativo.

Procure ler bastante código das implementações originais. [`SignInManager` está aqui](http://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/2.2.0-alpha1-140723/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/SignInManager.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin). [`UserManager`, aqui](http://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.0.0-rtm-140219/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core).